# Selenium WebDriver with Java NoSuchElementException timeout

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout, nosuchelementexception

I have a problem with the timeout time of the NoSuchElementException, it seem to be 30 seconds by default and I want to shorten it down. So I wrote something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
element.click();
```

And I get this message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be
clickable: By.id: someid

org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"id","selector":"someid"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.03 seconds
```

So the first message is what I was hoping that the WebDriverWait would override the NoSuchElementException timeout but I still get the full 30 seconds. Anyway, what's the way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some of these:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait()
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout()
```

Comment: hum implicitlyWait() actually worked, do u have any idea why the WebDriverWait method did not?

Comment: yes.  WebDriverWait did not work because you are calling elementToBeClickable.  I think might have wanted `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.invisiblilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someid")));`

Answer (score 2):

Wait for 10 sec in Selenium WedDriver with Java:

For Implicit wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

For Explicit wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someID")));
```